# Java Rest API : BMC Remedy API and JIRA Integration

Tags: java, rest, jira, remedy

I'm integrating BMC remedy and JIRA to solve a problem.

**Task:** I run a rest service and it raises automatic JIRA after reading BMC remedy if there are any records which are of type hotfix. So basically few fields from BMC will be mapped to JIRA when JIRA are created.

**Problem :**  Because Remedy API accepts only one search criteria (which is "hotFix" in my case), Every time my service runs it reads remedy and fetches all the data which are of type "hotFix" even the ones I've already created JIRAs for which is expected. But now i need to resolve this because I don't want to raise duplicate JIRAs for them.

I don't want store all these things in database due to some reason. (Well infra cost).

Is there any way I can import this data without creating duplicates?

Comment: Have you tried filtering by date created and using the last time you synchronized as criteria?  I don't see an easy way to do this short of comparing directly with JIRA to see if the issue is already there.

Comment: @zero298 thanks for the reply actually I can filter based on only one qualification parameter which is "hotFix" in my case. As the BMC emedy do not accept more than one qualification parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I'm using a flat file.

As an alternative solution I've used a flat file to store the "date created" of last remedy incident with "HotFix" label (only one record !!! this gets updated every time my service gets a hit if there are new remedy incidents) and while fetching the data from remedy I'm ordering it based on date created and storing the most updated date (which would effectively serve me as a parameter for comparison when i hit my service next time to check if JIRAs till this particular date/time has already been created.) in this file.

This has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your service before creating a JIRA ticket(I assume its an api call), check if already one exists (by using GET api from JIRA).

Based on your constraints for querying bmc remedy, seems this extra call to JIRA, to check if its a duplicate is an option.

Comment: hey Anil, Yes I've thought about it however was little reluctant to make an other search on JIRA before insert as it might impact service performance.

Comment: Looking at your constraints, thats the only option you have, its a tradeoff that u need accept

Comment: Also looking at this JIRA community currently there is no way to stop creating duplicate issues. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/I-would-like-to-know-if-it-s-possible-to-check-for-duplicate/qaq-p/156723